# How to check if the following array contains these characters?

Tags: c, arrays

So I have an array called password. I initiate the array as: `char password[3] = ""` and then fill it in using a while loop which takes one character at a time. The correct password is 123.

The following statement for checking if the password is 123 works:

```
 if (password[0] == '1' && password[1] == '2' && password[2] == '3')
```

But I wanted to use something like:

```
if (password[3] == {1,2,3})
```

It is less lines and more clear to understand. I seem to get syntax error with this particular one. I have also tried

```
if (password == "123")
```

but it doesn't accept 123 as the correct password. I am not sure if it is the same in c, but the string would end with slash 0 in c++, so I tried to add that at the end as well, again didn't work.

Is there a way to write it so that I don't have to use the AND gates?

Thank you for your help.

Updated code:

```
char password[4] = "";
int c = 0;
int flg;

void main(void)
{
 LATC = 0x00;
 TRISC = 0x0b10000000;

 //Clear Port B for now
 LATB = 0x00;
 TRISB = 0x00;


  OpenUSART(USART_TX_INT_OFF & USART_RX_INT_OFF & USART_ASYNCH_MODE &
  USART_EIGHT_BIT & USART_CONT_RX & USART_BRGH_HIGH, 64);


putrsUSART( " Welcome to your lock program. \r\n " ); // Send the string
Delay10KTCYx(400); // Delay between data transmissions
noPass = 1;

 while(noPass == 1)
 {
   putrsUSART(" \r\n\n Please type the password in: ");

  while (c<=2)
  {
    while(BusyUSART());
       // wait for user input
    while (!DataRdyUSART());
       //get string from terminal
      password[c] = getcUSART();       //read a byte from USART

       putrsUSART("\r\n\n You typed: "); 
       //Write a string from program memory to the USART
       putcUSART(password[c]);

       putrsUSART("\r\n\n");        
       c++;
  }

 //if (password[0] == '1' && password[1] == '2' && password[2] == '3' )
  if (strcmp(password, "123") == 0)
 //unlock
 {
 putrsUSART("\r\n\n Correct Pasword \r\n\n");
 //short time to unlock, set solenoid, then delay it, 
 //then reset it so it locks again. 
    Delay10KTCYx(1000); // Delay between data transmissions
   c = 0;
   noPass = 0;
}
  else
  {
 putrsUSART("\r\n\n Wrong password, please try again \r\n\n");
 c = 0;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: It would be good practice to nul terminate password after each new character is assigned. password[c+1] = ‘\0’. Also why do you have the wait for BusyUSART, seems like you should only need the wait for DataRdyUSART to become true for each character.

Comment: @Cmaster I'm using BusyUSART as it was used in example of a similar program to mine. I believe I have to use it as it checks if it is already transmitting, I think its more for error checking than anything else. I'm going to leave it in as it doesn't hurt to have it. Could you maybe explain why I'd null terminate after every character rather than after all characters are put in..? I'd like to know what difference it makes and why it would be considered good practice.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that `password[3]` can contain only strings up to a length of **2** because you need to account for the NUL string terminator. But even 3 is somewhat short for a password.

So you need at least

```
char password[4] = "";
```

And you must make sure that you vener copy passwords longer that 3 characters to `password`.

Furthermore string comparisions are done with `strcmp`.

Replace

```
if (password == "123")
```

with

```
if (strcmp(password, "123") == 0)
```

But be aware that `strcmp` can only operate on NUL terminated strings.

So you need this (I removed your comments, all comments are mine):

```
  while (c<=2)
  {
    while(BusyUSART());

    while (!DataRdyUSART());
      password[c] = getcUSART();

      putrsUSART("\r\n\n You typed: "); 
      putcUSART(password[c]);

      putrsUSART("\r\n\n");        
      c++;
  }

  password[c] = 0;    // NUL terminated the password

  if (strcmp(password, "123") == 0)
  {
    // password correct
  }
```

Comment: Oh I see, I've changed it to size 4 but even with the strcmp command I wasn't able to get it to recognize the correct password.

Comment: I've place it in now

Comment: You need to NUL terminate the password the user has entered

Comment: Hm... I've added 'password[c] = '\0';' after the while loop to NUL terminate it, but it still says wrong password. In fact, when I try to print using putrsUSART(password) I just get weird symbols instead of the numbers. Maybe I need to convert it in some way...

Comment: There must be some other problem. `strcmp` is the way to go.